# gnuplot two conditions in one ternary

Tags: gnuplot, ternary

There is a table consisted of four columns, such as

```
0.1   0.2   2   5
0.3   0.5   3   7 
0.2   0.9   4   8

0.5   0.2   5   5 

0.3   0.1   2   10

0.8   0.7   2   4
```

As you can see, there are empty rows.
What I want to do is to make a plot for this table, but I have two conditions. First, column 3 and 4 are plotted only if both column 1 and 2 ,respectively, are less than 0.4, so in this case, only 1st and 7th rows should be plotted. Second, empty rows should be ignored.

Easily, my plot should not show me any rows with no values, which means that row 4,6, and 7 should not be shown on the plot. Also, the first condition has to be satisfied.

so I typed like this,

```
reset
plot 'table.txt' u ($1 < 0.4 || $1 == 1/0 ? $3 : 1/0):($2 < 0.4 || $2 == 1/0 ? $4 : 1/0) pt 7 ps 0.5
```

but I could not get what I wanted.
Only two points, row 1 and 7, should be popped up, but those empty rows were also plotted.
Is that || (I used it as meaning of 'and') wrong?

Comment: `||` is logical `OR`, `&&` is logical `AND`. Check `help operators binary`, there is a list.

Answer (score 0):

Empty rows are not plotted anyway. So, use your ternary operator to check whether `$1<0.4 && $2<0.4`. If this is the case, put the current `$4` value into `y0` and `$3` into `x0`.... and plot `x0` and `y0`. In case you want to have connected lines, e.g. `with linespoints` you might need to take some more actions.

```
### filter data values
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.1   0.2   2   5
0.3   0.5   3   7 
0.2   0.9   4   8

0.5   0.2   5   5 

0.3   0.1   2   10

0.8   0.7   2   4
EOD

x0 = y0 = NaN
plot $Data u ($1<0.4 && $2<0.4 ? (y0=$4, x0=$3) : NaN):(y0) w p pt 7 ps 2
### end of code
```